# PDO insert and select statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to do a select and insert statement using PDO. As you can see, I have managed to create a query for insert into users and I have got a message left node 1 added successfully. However, the problem here is when I look into the sql database. There are no records of my data. I have done an echo statement and it seems that my variables are being output correctly.

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
if (isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) {
      $uname        = trim($_POST['user_name']);
      $uic        = trim($_POST['user_ic']);
      $email        = trim($_POST['user_email']);
      $upass        = trim($_POST['password']);

      $new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

     $query = $dbh->prepare("select * from users");
       $query->execute();   
    if($query){
          while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
              $enroller_id3 = $row['enroller_ID'];
              $test         = "left_mem";
            $test2        = "right_mem";
            $direc        = $direction;
          }
    }


?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: You're using this twice `:enrolled_id_n,
                :enroller_id_n` --- `":enrolled_id_n" => $enrolled_id_n,
                    ":enroller_id_n"=> $enroller_id_n,` and probably erroring out because of a possible constraint on a duplicate entry.

Comment: You also didn't execute `$sql = "insert into personally_enrolled...` you only prepared it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has MANY bugs:

```
   $query->execute();   
if($query){
```

`$query` is your statement handle and will ALWAYS be "true". If the `execute()` fails, it **RETURNS** that fact. `$query` will not magically become `false`.

You should have:

```
$result = $query->execute();
if(!$result) {
```

Then you have this:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO users
     (user_Name, user_ID, user_Email, user_Pass, enrolled_ID, enroller_ID, enroller_Postion, direction, country)
 VALUES
     (:uname,               :email, :new_password,:enrolled_id_n,
                :enroller_id_n, :uposition, :direc, :ucountry)";
```

See anything missing in there? You have 9 fields and 8 parameters. Since you don't bother checking if the query succeeded, you LIE about the success of the operation.

Comment: Plus, `$sql = "insert into personally_enrolled...` is only prepared, never executed.

Comment: no user id auto incremented. Thus i didn't enter any parameter field for it, but it in fact added successfully

Comment: not possible. PDO **SHOULD** have failed with a field/value mismatch and/or insufficient values bound to parameters error. fields and values are matched 1:1. mysql will not "magically" skip from :uname->:email and fill in user_ID for you.